# XamlReader.Load can't find static resources

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Creating column at runtime, with DataTemplateSelector. Have exception at XamlReader.Load: System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension. How can i load resources?

```
var column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            column.Header = (i.Hour + 1).ToString();
            column.Width = 30;
var parserContext = new ParserContext();
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("local", "clr-namespace:ССПИ;assembly=ССПИ");
column.CellTemplateSelector = (DataTemplateSelector)XamlReader.Load(
                new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(
                    @"<local:ExtendedTemplateSelector TextBlockTemplate='{StaticResource TextBlockTemplate}' CheckBoxTemplate='{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate}'/>"
                )),parserContext);        
dataGrid1.Columns.Add(column);

<DataGrid DataGridCell.Selected="DataGrid_GotFocus" EnableColumnVirtualization="true" EnableRowVirtualization="true" Name="dataGrid1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                   Height="120" Width="Auto" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_CellEditEnding" ContextMenuOpening="dataGrid1_ContextMenuOpening">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBlockTemplate">
                            <TextBlock/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="False"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your App.xaml:

```
<App.Resources>
    <local:ExtendedTemplateSelector x:Key="MyExtendedTemplateSelector" TextBlockTemplate='{StaticResource TextBlockTemplate}' CheckBoxTemplate='{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate}'/>
</App.Resources>
```

in your .cs:

```
column.CellTemplateSelector = (DataTemplateSelector)((App)Application.Current)).Resources["MyExtendedTemplateSelector"];
```

As far as I can see, you don't need a parser here: it'll just make things complicated and slower. So just put you resource in your APP resources (or in a resourceDictionary) and call it like this